# NaN while finding Difference using momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs, flatpickr

I am using `flatpickr` to get date from the user. I am getting two dates from the user. Now I want to find the difference between two dates but its showing `NaN`.
[image]

```
 computed: {
    total() {
      if (this.selectedRooms && this.selectedRooms.length) {
        const check_in = moment(this.form.check_in, "d-m-Y H:i");
        const check_out = moment(this.form.check_out, "d-m-Y H:i");

        const nights = check_in.diff(check_out, "days");
       
        let total = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedRooms.length; i++) {
          if (this.invoice.nights) {
            total += +this.selectedRooms[i][this.type] * +nights;
          } else {
            total += +this.selectedRooms[i][this.type];
          }
        }
        return total;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    }
}
```

Flatpickr config

```
 configdateTimePicker: {
        enableTime: true,
        dateFormat: "d-m-Y H:i",
      },
```

Error

```
NaN
```

When I try it without parsing dates it's showing me Invalid date

Comment: I am using vue just for demonstration I used variables date1 & date2 please check I have included a photo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatting/parsing tokens are different in [`flatpickr`](https://flatpickr.js.org/formatting/) and `moment`. So when parsing to moment object, you must follow [moment formatting/parsing token](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)

```js
const date1 = "25-08-2020 21:38"
const date2 = "26-08-2020 21:38"
const firstDate = moment(date1, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm")
const secondDate = moment(date2, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm")

console.log(firstDate.diff(secondDate, "days"))
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Use `console.log(secondDate.diff(firstDate, "days"))`  for postive value

Answer (score 0):

Formatting is not required to find the Date diff . You can use the below code .

```
 const date1 = '2020-08-25 12:00:00';
        const date2 = '2020-08-26 12:00:00';
        const firstDate = moment(date1);
        const secondDate = moment(date2);
       console.log(firstDate.diff(secondDate, "days"))
```